# how to control add view in android?

Tags: android, view, controls, addition

I'm a beginner of Android. I'm trying to control it by adding several dynamic views. What I want to do is add, delete, and bringfront view work. But I'm not doing it. I attach my code. The biggest problem I face the most is the following.
I'd like to create two views and then do a bringfront, but it only applies to the most late created views.
I want you to tell me how to solve it.

```
public class Fit_Me_page extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private RecyclerView fit_me_recyclerview;
    private ArrayList<Fit_Me_Array> fit_me_arrays;
    private Fit_Me_Adapter fit_me_adapter;
    Fit_Me_Category_Array fit_me_all_category_array;
    int category_number = 0;
    ConstraintLayout fit_me_constraintLayout;
    private ConstraintSet applyConstraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    TextView textView, textView2;
    ImageView imageView;
    ImageView imageView2;
    ImageView testView;
    ArrayList<String> category_array_1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> category_array_2;
    ImageView show_cloth_information_btn, cloth_size_up_btn, cloth_size_down_btn,
            compare_my_size_btn, cloth_bring_front_btn, cloth_send_back_btn, cloth_delete_btn;
    int number = 0;
    int i = 11;
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fit_me_page);
        show_cloth_information_btn = findViewById(R.id.show_cloth_information);
        cloth_size_up_btn = findViewById(R.id.cloth_size_up);
        cloth_size_down_btn = findViewById(R.id.cloth_size_down);
        compare_my_size_btn = findViewById(R.id.check_my_size);
        cloth_bring_front_btn = findViewById(R.id.front_image);
        cloth_send_back_btn = findViewById(R.id.back_image);
        cloth_delete_btn = findViewById(R.id.delete_image);
        fit_me_recyclerview = findViewById(R.id.fit_me_recyclerview);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
        fit_me_arrays = new ArrayList<>();
        fit_me_adapter = new Fit_Me_Adapter(this, fit_me_arrays);
        fit_me_recyclerview.setAdapter(fit_me_adapter);
        fit_me_recyclerview.addItemDecoration(new grid_view_padding(this));
        fit_me_recyclerview.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        fit_me_constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.fit_me_ConstraintLayout);
        fit_me_all_category_array = new Fit_Me_Category_Array();
        testView = new ImageView(Fit_Me_page.this);
        fit_me_constraintLayout.addView(testView);
        imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        fit_me_adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new Fit_Me_Adapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                if (position == 1 && category_number == 0) {
                    fit_me_arrays.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < fit_me_all_category_array.categoryOuter.size(); i++) {
                        Fit_Me_Array fit_me_array = new Fit_Me_Array(fit_me_all_category_array.categoryOuter.get(i));
                        fit_me_arrays.add(fit_me_array);
                    }
                    category_number++;
                    fit_me_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else if (position == 1 && category_number == 1) {
                    imageView = new ImageView(Fit_Me_page.this);
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.color_wheel);
                    // imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    imageView.bringToFront();
                    imageView.setOnTouchListener(Fit_Me_page.this::onTouch);
                    //imageView.setOnLongClickListener(Fit_Me_page.this::onLongClick);
                    i++;
                    imageView.setId(i);
                    fit_me_constraintLayout.addView(imageView);
                } else if (position == 2 && category_number == 1) {
                    // ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(M,700);
                    imageView = new ImageView(Fit_Me_page.this);
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.camera_button);
                    // imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    imageView.bringToFront();
                    imageView.setOnTouchListener(Fit_Me_page.this::onTouch);
                    //imageView.setOnLongClickListener(Fit_Me_page.this::onLongClick);
                    i++;
                    imageView.setId(i);
                    fit_me_constraintLayout.addView(imageView);
                } else if (position == 0 && category_number == 1) {
                    fit_me_arrays.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < fit_me_all_category_array.categoryAll.size(); i++) {
                        Fit_Me_Array fit_me_array = new Fit_Me_Array(fit_me_all_category_array.categoryAll().get(i));
                        fit_me_arrays.add(fit_me_array);
                    }
                    fit_me_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    category_number--;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        show_cloth_information_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imageView2.bringToFront();
            }
        });

        cloth_size_up_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        cloth_size_down_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        compare_my_size_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
        cloth_bring_front_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                testView = fit_me_constraintLayout.findFocus().findViewById(number);
                testView.bringToFront();
            }
        });

        cloth_send_back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        cloth_delete_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    float oldXvalue;
    float oldYvalue;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int parentWidth = ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).getWidth();    // 부모 View 의 Width
        int parentHeight = ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).getHeight();    // 부모 View 의 Height

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // 뷰 누름
            Log.d("바로?", "onTouch: " + "다운");
            oldXvalue = event.getX();
            oldYvalue = event.getY();
            number = v.getId();
            testView.setId(number);
            return true;

        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            Log.d("바로?", "onTouch: " + "무브");
            v.setX(v.getX() + (event.getX()) - oldXvalue);
            v.setY(v.getY() + (event.getY()) - oldYvalue);
            Log.d("viewTest", "onTouch: ");
            Log.d("viewTest", "onTouch: ");
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (v.getX() < 0) {
                v.setX(0);
            } else if ((v.getX() + v.getWidth()) > parentWidth) {
                v.setX(parentWidth - v.getWidth());
            }

            if (v.getY() < 0) {
                v.setY(0);
            } else if ((v.getY() + v.getHeight()) > parentHeight) {
                v.setY(parentHeight - v.getHeight());
            }
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: if there are only two views that you have to brintfront, then can hide 1 view and show other one, View.GONE & VIew.VISIBLE.  
if there are more then two let me know.

Comment: thank you for your help. There are more than two dynamic views I am trying to control.! When I click on one of the dynamically created views, I want to delete the view or send it to the front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fit_me_constraintLayout.addView(imageView);
```

You had used this to add view correct..
Layout will add view just like list 1 after other, so you just need to remove that particular view and add it again, it will be on top.
So where ever you need to perform brintToFront.

```
 fit_me_constraintLayout.removeView(imageView);
 fit_me_constraintLayout.addView(imageView);
```

**AFTER EDIT**

```
 cloth_bring_front_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    testView = fit_me_constraintLayout.findFocus().findViewById(number);
                    if(testView !=null){
                      fit_me_constraintLayout.removeView(testView );
                      fit_me_constraintLayout.addView(testView );}
                     }
            });
```

Let me know if that words

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. The part where I want to do the bringfront.
 cloth_bring_front_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                testView = fit_me_constraintLayout.findFocus().findViewById(number);
                testView.bringToFront();
            }
        });

Comment: Here's the problem I'm facing. Multiple view objects are created with the name imageview. However, the id value of the imageview generated is different. Here, you want to specify an id value through onTouchListener and then bring the imageview object corresponding to that id value forward, but it only works in the imageview that was created last.

Comment: Ok.. let me know if that works else can you please make edit and give me the layout you needed to can provide exact one.

Comment: What if it's a different layout? You mean the full code?

Comment: No i don't need full code, the thing you actually want to achieve . 

If constraint layout /Relative Layout / Frame Layout it will work same, for other behavior might change. method will be same addVIew/RemoveVIew

Comment: Do you mean to change the contrast layout to a different kind of layout and test it?
I'm sorry if you're wrong. I want you to know that I can be a little wrong because I understand you through the translator.

Comment: And as per the above answer, NullPointerException has occurred.